# Databricks- CSV FILE last column has multiilpe seprators(wanted tht in single column)

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to process the csv file where the last column has multiple(commas) which separated them into multiple columns

expected columns 7 (1 to 6 ) in proper format after [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzFiz.png)6th(coma) we need all the data in one column

**Sample line with headers:**

```
SEQUENCE    CHECK_TIME  DEVICE  ORIGIN  NAMESPACE   SERVICE_CHECK   VALUE   TAGS
0   2020-06-24T02:00:05.441Z    kubeflow-vm vm.azm.ms/map   Computer    Heartbeat   1   {"vm.azm.ms/processIds":["p-96566f30b8066a6479008755c528d7920511edc8","p-9f6667971df49fed675576b8f936cc45a61d242d","p-cfc973bcf0a32b902410a7b16cd977d6bb264e62","p-39a51e264bf790ec9e4a6902ead00101c1e78c97","p-d63478488b88c35f85a2c11e07642dddec84ef62","p-ce8cf40e9b45c9db18007f181460e21587af3267","p-e2643b874c714b4dd182003298ad59268f7f6b5b","p-0efa4aa396315bfcd87632237460ab0c12124c46","p-642d2b7e86ff01c62bc11f858e074e741d54d37b","p-0a3fbb9d81230bee9daaa2ce8262bb5357debb69","p-f61381ae6a9c8cdad1f241c9c456015658a8f925","p-f3f604a0313bc1778e69c9203a0162d1abfedad2","p-6dec6d0558740906471b6d3ee920cce37faeca70","p-27613669fcf7faaeef5023acc6505973e12d2db5","p-d97d079b692dcb81adb5ed5dc48d29c82ef6f93a","p-44507943475c4fb04f09595617020da7ac2c388c"]}
```

trying get this in python but we are not able to could you pls help

push the data to a dataframe or table

Answer (score 0):

The `.option('escape','"')` helped me in a similar situation:

```
# .option('escape','"') is crucial for dealing with commas inside a field
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").options(header= "true", inferschema='true').option('escape','"').load(path)
```

Comment: Thanks matkurek this helped, iam to get the last coulmn in single row!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following steps.

**Step1:** Declare the path

```
path= "/FileStore/tables/samplearray.csv"
```

**Step2:** Load into the dataframe using the following option escape.

> **escape**: the escape character. By default , but can be set to any character. Escaped quote characters are written.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").options(header= "true", inferschema='true').option('escape','"').load(path)
```

**Step3:** Display data frame.

[image]